# PHP Horde imap fetch with PEEK

Tags: php, imap, horde

Is it possible with Horde to FETCH with PEEK mode ? So the mail will be still unseen after I fetched it.

```
$fetchQuery =  new Horde_Imap_Client_Fetch_Query();
$fetchQuery->fullText();


/** @var Horde_Imap_Client_Fetch_Results $mail */
$results = $client->fetch('INBOX', $fetchQuery, ['ids' => new Horde_Imap_Client_Ids(11632)]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Set parameter 'peek' to true, and it makes horde to fetch mail in PEEK mode. 
Such way the fetching mail will not be flagged as seen.

```
$fetchQuery->fullText(['peek' => true]);
```

Comment: While answering your own questions is fine, the answer should be full and informative.  One line of code does not make a good answer.